# Opengl-es : How to access corners of a texel

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, shader

I have a texel (rectangle) and I need to access its 4 corners.

```
vec2 offset = vec2(1,1)/vec2(texWidth, texHeight)
texture2D (texSource, texCoord + 0.5 * offset * ???? )
```

what should  I fill here to get both top 2 and bottom 2 corners.?

[Edit] : Code as per Tommy's answer

```
" vec2 pixelSize = vec2(offsetx,offsety);\n" +
" vec2 halfPixelSize = pixelSize * vec2(0.5);\n" +
" vec2 texCoordCentre = vTextureCoord - mod(vTextureCoord, pixelSize) + halfPixelSize;\n" +
" vec2 topLeft = texCoordCentre - halfPixelSize;\n" +
" vec2 bottomRight = texCoordCentre + halfPixelSize;\n" +
" vec2 topRight = texCoordCentre + vec2(halfPixelSize.x, -halfPixelSize.y);\n" +
" vec2 bottomLeft = texCoordCentre + vec2(-halfPixelSize.x, halfPixelSize.y);\n" +
" vec4 p00 = texture2D(sTexture, topLeft);\n" +
" vec4 p02 = texture2D(sTexture, bottomRight);\n" +
" vec4 p20 = texture2D(sTexture, topRight);\n" +
" vec4 p22 = texture2D(sTexture, bottomLeft);\n" +
" vec4 pconv = 0.25*(p00 + p02 + p20 + p22);\n" +
```

Answer (score 1):

A texture is always addressed by numbers in the range [0, 1). Taking a texel as being an individual pixel within a texture, each of those is an equal subdivision of the range [0, 1), hence if there are 16 of them the first occupies the region [0, 1/16), the next [1/16, 2/16), etc.

So the boundaries of the texel at n in a texture of size p are at n/p and n+1/p, and the four corners are at the combinations of the boundary positions for x and y.

If you have linear filtering enabled then you'll get an equal mix of the four adjoining texels by sampling at those locations; if you've got nearest filtering enabled then you'll get one of the four but be heavily subject to floating point rounding errors.

So, I think:

```
vec2 pixelSize = vec2(1.0) / vec2(texWidth, texHeight);
vec2 halfPixelSize = pixelSize * vec2(0.5);
vec2 texCoordCentre = texCoord - mod(texCoord, pixelSize) + halfPixelSize;

vec2 topLeft = texCoordCentre - halfPixelSize;
vec2 bottomRight = texCoordCentre + halfPixelSize;
vec2 topRight = texCoordCentre + vec2(halfPixelSize.x, -halfPixelSize.y);
vec2 bottomLeft = texCoordCentre + vec2(-halfPixelSize.x, halfPixelSize.y);
```

(... and if you were targeting ES 3 instead of 2, you could just use the `textureSize` function instead of messing about with uniforms)

Comment: Thank you Tommy for the detailed answer. I did the code like you have suggested. 
Ultimately I wanted to calculate the convolued value of a texel by sampling its 4 corners so as to get same results as 3x3 gaussian blur convolution.
But I got a large variation between both approaches. Variation in R , G and B upto 5 was acceptable (between this approach and Gaussain-blur ).
But I got variations upto 42.                                                                     I have added code as part of my question as I couldnt add in comment. I am using GL_LINEAR For texture mapping in both cases.